# orthogonal distance from fit with scipy.odr

Tags: python, scipy, linear-regression, orthogonal

I perform an ODR fit for given data points with x and y uncertainty with `scipy.odr`. For the fit result I would like to see the orthogonal distances of each point from the fit. This can be easily computed for a linear fit function but it can be more complicated for an arbitrary function. Since `scipy.odr` is minimizing these distances it has to compute them, so maybe one can directly access them but I did not find it in the documentation. Maybe I missed it? Any ideas?

So for the attached example code I would like to get an array of 100 elements containing the orthogonal distances and then e.g. plot a histogram.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.odr import *

np.random.seed(1)

N = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 10, N)
y = 3*x - 1 + np.random.random(N)
sx = np.random.random(N)
sy = np.random.random(N)

def f(B, x):
    return B[0]*x + B[1]

linear = Model(f)
mydata = RealData(x, y, sx=sx, sy=sy)

myodr = ODR(mydata, linear, beta0=[1., 2.])
myoutput = myodr.run()
myoutput.pprint()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a quick look in the documentation I think the model estimates for the orthogonal distance are what it brings input errors in `myoutput.delta` and output errors in `myoutput.eps`, combine the two of them we can get an estimate of the orthogonal distance.

Using the calculated `y` error, for this linear model we can use some geometry to find the orthogonal distance that is `dy * sqrt(10/81)`

```py
dy = (y - f(myoutput.beta, x))
orthogonal = np.sqrt((dy / 3)**2 + (dy / 9)**2)
plt.plot(dy, np.sqrt(myoutput.delta**2 + myoutput.eps**2), '.', label='Estimated orthogonal distance')
plt.plot(dy, orthogonal, '.', label='Exact orthogonal distance')
plt.xlabel('Vertical distance')
plt.ylabel('Orthogonal distance')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

It is reasonable that the estimates are higher than the actual value, since it may be not estimating properly the closest point in the fitted curve.

Comment: thanks. I read delta = 'Array of estimated errors in input variables, of same shape as x.' like my input error provided to the 'Data' object. But that does not really make sense, I guess your interpretation is more reasonable :)